# WeakHashMap<Integer, Vector<IConsumer>>, will Vector be collected if only strong reference to IConsumers?

Tags: java, multithreading, garbage-collection, weak-references, producer-consumer

I have an object `Producer` which internally starts a thread that will listen for some network events, and at most times block on a `receive()` method. In this `Producer` object I have a `WeakHashMap<Integer, Vector<IConsumer>>` containing at hash map with keys being the events that the `Producer` can produce, and the value being a list of consumer that has registered on these events.

Now I have a `Main` object which constructs some `Manager`. The `Manager` the constructs one single `Producer` and any number of `ConcreteConsumers implements IConsumer`. The `Manager` contains a reference to the `Producer` and the `ConcreteConsumer`s.

**Is this a valid construction, will the `Vector<IConsumer>` not be eligible for GC immediately after insertion in the `WeakHashMap<Integer, Vector<IConsumer>>` as there are not reference to the actual vector? There are only references to the `Producer` and the `ConcreteConsumer`s directly. If so, how can I solve this?**

---

Next what happens is that the `Main` object drops the reference to the `Manager`, which should cause all the `ConcreteConsumers` to be eligible for GC, which is what I want.

**But, I also want the actual `Producer` object to be eligible for GC and for the internal thread to stop executing at this point. Any suggestions on how to do this?**

Comment: What are the key and value types of your map? - "An *entry* in a WeakHashMap will automatically be removed when its *key* is no longer in ordinary use."

Comment: @HannoBinder: I forgot to write the actual key of the hashmap, it is an Integer, I updated the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the key in `WeakHashMap` that has the weak reference. The value is strongly referenced. The entry will be removed some time after there are no strong references to the key, an `Integer` in this case. That is the very same instance of `Integer`, not just an instance with the same value. Values types aren't particularly useful as keys to `WeakHashMap`.

(`WeakHashMap` is not useful as a cache (you want to be using `SoftReference`s, and probably someone else's library).)

Comment: "That is the very same instance of Integer, not just an instance with the same value." - Maybe one should note Java's internal 'caching' of `Integer` objects which may prevent them from ever being collected.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. It seems I misunderstood `WeakHashMap` completely, as I somehow misread the documentation as the value being the one kept by a weak reference. I replaced the map structure with a `HashMap<Integer, Set<IConsumer>>` where the Set gets constructed by `Collections.newSetFromMap(WeakHashMap...)`, which as far as I can read does what I want.